# How to prevent "extra space" caused by focusing an offscreen element in Chrome?

Tags: css, google-chrome, focus

I have an issue where extra space is being created on the page (outside the HTML element) when focusing an element that's transitioning from *outside* the viewport.

This seems to *only* happen in Chrome.

I have trouble Googling precisely this issue, but I have a [reproduction here](https://www.abefehr.com/transition-test/)

I've tried supplying `overflow-x: hidden` to `html, body` but that doesn't seem to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding `overflow:hidden` to `form` or `.step-container`?

Comment: If I apply `overflow: hidden` to the `.step-container` it fades the input in, but doesn't translate it in anymore  this might be a "good enough" solution though! Thanks for that.